# Одновременная загрузка изображений php

Tags: php

Есть метод которы подключается к удаленному ftp 
Где находится 1000 файлов. Он отдает запрос на загрузку и поочереди загружает их. Но время выполнения скрипта равно примерно часу и серсер после лимита времени убивает выполнение скрипта.
Вопрос, можно ли как то загрузить непрерывно изоброжения?
Как это правильно делается , подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Через ftp-клиент? FileZilla какая-нить, или totalcmd. Зачем скрипт для одноразовой задачи?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно, мое решение вам покажется немного сложным, но я постараюсь описать вам свое видение решения проблемы. Если задача выполняется постоянно и планируется расширение, возможно Вам подойдет.

К сожалению, от скрипта в цикле и постоянного его выполнения это Вас не избавит, но поднимет производительность и надежность архитектурного решения по скачиванию большого количества файлов.

Пусть у вас есть сервер очередей (например, RabbitMQ), и есть 3 скрипта:

1. Скрипт выполняющий получение всех названий файлов на сервере
2. Скрипт выполняющий загрузку файлов с сервера
3. Скрипт выполняющий обработку файлов, загруженных с сервера.

Вы создаете очередь, называете ее files_download, на эту очередь вешаете консьюмера (скрипт, выполняющий задания из очереди и постоянно ее проверяющий). Раз в n-времени, запускаете свой скрипт по cron, который будет получать список файлов c сервера (ftp_nlist) и формировать его на основе какого-то алгоритма (что скачивать, что нет), далее, отправляете n-заданий (n - количество файлов) в очередь files_download, и качаете их с помощью скрипта который уже следит за очередью по одному.

Задания в очередь ставятся чаще всего со всей нужной информацией на основе JSON, предположим задание на скачивание будет выглядеть примерно вот так:

```
{"file": "ftp://my.server.com/file1.pdf"}
```

Можно добавлять дополнительные параметры, если они требуются скрипту.

Далее, по необходимости, после скачивания файла ставится задание на его обработку в другую очередь (files_processing) и выполняются какие-то другие сложные действия по конвертации и т.д.

Плюс данного решения в том, что вы никогда не потеряете файлы которые нужно скачать, можете повесить на очередь **хоть 50 консьюмеров и качать в 50 потоков с разных серверов** (все ограничено только клиентской и серверной пропускной способностью и количеством возможных коннектов) не поднимая многопоточность на уровне PHP, все будет контролировать очередь сообщений обеспечивая надежное выполнение заданий.

Comment: Можете скинуть ресурсы где можно почитать про такую реализацию?

Comment: Честно говоря, ресурсов не знаю, т.к. на основе знаний по очередям это делается за пару часов, вот ссылка на туториал по rabbitmq: http://ajaxblog.ru/php/rabbitmq-tutorial/

Answer (score 2):

Убрать ограничение времени можно функцией [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-time-limit.php)
Если скрипт запускается из браузера, не лишено смысла также игнорировать потерю соединения с клиентом: [ignore_user_abort](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ignore-user-abort.php)

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
```